# Joomla 4 Webservices Basic Auth "forbidden"

Tags: authentication, web-services, joomla

I'm using the Joomla 4 Webservices API in a mobile App. The app shows articles from the website but Admins should also be able to login within the app and create new articles.

Everything works great except the login. I try to use basic auth but I always get the result "forbidden". I also tried it in Postman. Username and password are correct, the Baisc Auth plugin is enabled in Joomla.
I read something about security concerns. Is it actually not available anymore?

If so what is my alternative? I can't use the token based auth. It works, I tried it but I can't ask the admins to enter the token as a login.

Thanks!